# Fetch OpportunityLIneItem along with OpportunityId in Map

Tags: apex, map

```
Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>> oliList=new Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
 for(Opportunity opp:eligibleOpp)
           {
               if(opp.opportunitylineitems.size()>0)
               {
                if(oliList.containsKey(opp.Id))
                   {  
                    oliList.get(opp.Id).add(opp.opportunitylineitems);
                    System.debug('Map values iteration '+oliList);

                   }
                else
                  { oliList.put(opp.Id,new list<OpportunityLineItem>{opp.OpportunityLineItems}); 
                     oliListToDel.add(opp.OpportunityLineItems); 
                     System.debug('Map values iteration else con'+oliList);

                  }           
               }
           }
```

---

On this line I am getting error :

`oliList.put(opp.Id,new list<OpportunityLineItem>{opp.OpportunityLineItems}`

Please help me on this. I am getting

> List has more than 1 rows for assignment.

Even if  I have taken list of lineitems still I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for creating a list as a copy of another list is

`List<sObject> myList = new List(someOtherList);`

rather than the `{}` notation used to write list literals.

Here, you don't need to create a new list at all. Just put `opp.OpportunityLineItems` directly into your Map.